Happy Square Year!
Some of you math nerds may be looking forward to the year 2025 because it's a square number: 2025 = 452.
But not just any square number: It's the square of the sum of the two-digit numbers resulting from cutting the digit string in half: 2025 = (20 + 25)2.
This is a rare phenomenon that will never occur again within our lifetimes (unless immortality happens somehow), and in fact will only happen twice more during the entire era of four-digit years.
What are the other two four-digit numbers that share 2025's special property?  No brute-force, please.

Write A and B for the two "halves". Then $(A+B)^2=100A+B$

 Substituting $C:=A+B$ this becomes $C(C-1)=99A$.


 With the constraints $44<C<100$ and both $11$ and $9$ dividing either $C$ or $C-1$ there are only a handful of cases to consider: $C=45$ as shown in OP, $C=55$ which gives $A=30;B=25$ and $C=99$ which gives $A=98,B=1$.

